# Invoke a C# inner Expression with a member property of a parameter to an outer expression

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, expression-trees

I am using the Albaharis PredicateBuilder as found here http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx to filter results in a Linq-to-SQL application. This has been working great.

What I am trying to do now, is reuse the existing filtering predicate expression to filter an object that has the existing filtered object as a property.

For example, I have 2 classes, `Order` and `Customer`.  I already have a method that returns a `Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>`, which is built using the above mentioned predicate builder.  I now want to reuse this in my `Order` filtering method, which will return a `Expression<Func<Customer, bool>>` by somehow passing the `Order.Customer` property (expression?) into my `Customer` filter method.

I have something like this (far from complete, but I hope you get the idea):

```
public class CustomerSearchCriteria
{
    public Expression<Func<Customer, bool>> FilterPredicate()
    {
        // Start with predicate to include everything
        var result = PredicateBuilder.True<Customer>();

        // Build predicate from criteria
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Name))
        {
            result = result.And(c => SqlMethods.Like(c.Name, this.Name));
        }

        // etc. etc. etc

} 


public class OrderSearchCriteria
{
    public Expression<Func<Order, bool>> FilterPredicate()
    {
        // Start with predicate to include everything
        var result = PredicateBuilder.True<Order>();

        // Build predicate from criteria
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Reference))
        {
            result = result.And(o => SqlMethods.Like(o.Reference, this.Reference));
        }

        // etc. etc. etc
        // This is where I would like to do something like:
        // result = result.And(o => o.Customer "matches" this.CustomerCriteria.FilterPredicate()
}
```

Can any Linq expression guru help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Albaharis' [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx), you should be able to do something like this:

```
var customerFilter = this.CustomerCriteria.FilterPredicate();
// create an expression that shows us invoking the filter on o.Customer
Expression<Func<Order, bool>> customerOrderFilter = 
    o => customerFilter.Invoke(o.Customer);
// "Expand" the expression: this creates a new expression tree
// where the "Invoke" is replaced by the actual predicate.
result = result.And(customerOrderFilter.Expand())
```

Comment: Thanks very much. That's exactly what I need. I was using PredicateBuilder, but hadn't included or looked at the rest of LinqKit.